# linq orderby.tolist() performance

Tags: c#, performance, linq, sql-order-by, linq-to-objects

I have an ordering query to a List and calling for many times. 
`list = list.OrderBy().ToList();`
In this code ToList() method is spending high resources and takes very long time. How can I speed up with another ordering method without converting back to a list. Should I use .Sort extension for arrays?

Comment: `List<T>` has its own `Sort()` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx

Comment: Note that `OrderBy` is lazily evaluated, calling `ToList` forces that evaluation to happen. Questions to ask: is your `OrderBy` doing anything expensive such as making method calls? How big is your source?

Comment: In fact I have a class which has start and finish dates and this list is ordering for start times. I am adding and removing these objects maybe for a million times (this is a simulation). How can I keep it in sorted while adding an object? I think inserting to the spesific index is needed, so I need to filter on each adding. Maybe this needs more resources, I'm not sure...

Comment: @Baran Maybe instead you want something like a [`SortedList<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedlist-2?view=netframework-4.7.1) or [`SortedSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1?view=netframework-4.7.1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, try to sort the list once, and keep it sorted.

To speed up things you can use Parallel LINQ.

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163329.aspx

An OrderBy() Parallel looks like this:

```
 var query = data.AsParallel().Where(x => p(x)).Orderby(x => k(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Ordering for one time is very fast but calling again and again makes it slow. I think in this situation using parallel makes it more slower. But thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call ToList() once to get your sorted list. All future actions should use sortedList.

```
sortedList = list.OrderBy().ToList();
```